# Print detents for potentiometers

Tags: 3d-design

**Problem**: Detent potentiometers (think potentiometers with haptic feedback) are expensive and I need like 15 of them for my project (maybe 4-5 different detent levels, which means no bulk discounts :/ ).

**Question**: How would you guys 3D print haptic feedback for potentiometers?

Please consider:

- My project would have a 3D-printed faceplate and caps for all potentiometers.
- I have an idea in my mind but I think friction will wear it down quite quickly. I would print sunken dots on the faceplate and a raised dot on the potentiometer cap to fit into the sunken dots on the faceplate. Also, I am worried the cap would just raise itself away from the faceplate and render the sunken dots useless.

Comment: Maybe mess w/ this model: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:928841?

Comment: @TheTridentGuysupportsUkraine Looks like a great idea actually. It would seem that wear down will still be an issue but I'd imagine it will be slower cause there is just much more materials. Thank you!